# Como converter all_timezones para outro formato

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou precisando converter os timezones do `pytz` para o seguinte formato abaixo, mas esto com dificuldades de fazer isto com python. Como funciona este tipo do conversão?

```
from pytz import all_timezones

time_zones = [{
       u'value': u'1',
       u'text': (u'Africa/Abidjan')
   }, {
     u'value': u'2',
     u'text': (u'Africa/Accra')
  }...]
```

A saida do print(all_timezones) é:

```
('all_timezones', ['Africa/Abidjan', 'Africa/Accra', 'Africa/Addis_Ababa', 'Africa/Algiers' ... ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade `all_timezones` é uma lista contendo os nomes dos timezones. Se você quer criar outra lista contendo dicionários (que por sua vez contêm um número sequencial e o nome do timezone), basta fazer:

```
timezones = []
for i, tz in enumerate(all_timezones):
    timezones.append({ 'value': str(i + 1), 'text': tz })
```

Com [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) você percorre a lista e seus respectivos índices ao mesmo tempo.

Dito isso, não sei qual a vantagem de criar dicionários cujo `value` é um número sequencial, pois listas já possuem seus elementos em índices numéricos sequenciais (a diferença é que começa no zero em vez do 1). Se a ideia é procurar um elemento pelo índice numérico, uma lista é muito melhor para tal (basta fazer `all_timezones[numero]` - lembrando que o primeiro elemento está no índice zero, o segundo no índice 1, etc).

---

Outra alternativa é usar uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
timezones = [ { 'value': str(i + 1), 'text': tz } for i, tz in enumerate(all_timezones) ]
```

Comment: muito obrigado por todas explicações, vou estudar sobre list comprehension, concordo sua explicação em relação a vantagem. Mas como criaram no projeto desta forma não posso alterar.